# how to clear the session and token of facebook id,so as to login again

Tags: android, facebook

im my application,i can login to facebook and get the data,but when i click on logout,and then click on login again,it toast the message already login,but i want after logout,on login it again ask the login id and password,as all login requires.in on destroy i tried to clear the session,but it shows an error null exception in onDestroy. please suggest somthing

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Facebook fb;
    Button login,getData,logout;    
    ImageView ig;
    String app_id;
    String access_token;
    long expires;
    private static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
         app_id= getString(R.string.app_id);
         fb= new Facebook(app_id);
            login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
            getData=(Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
            // ig= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
             login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        loginToFacebook();
                    }
                });

    getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getProfileInformation();
        }
    });
         logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            Session.initializeStaticContext(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
            logoutFromFacebook();
        }

    }
    });
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
    //updateButtonImage();
    try {

        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
         md.update(signature.toByteArray());
         Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }

       } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
       }    
        }




        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void loginToFacebook() {

            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
         expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) {
                fb.setAccessToken(access_token);

                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Making get profile button visible
                getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + fb.isSessionValid());
            }

            if (expires != 0) {
                fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "already login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


            if (!fb.isSessionValid()) {
                fb.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                        new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // Function to handle cancel event
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // Function to handle complete event
                                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                             editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        fb.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        fb.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();

                                // Making Login button invisible
                                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                // Making logout Button visible
                                getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                // Function to handle error

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                // Function to handle Facebook errors

                            }

                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void getProfileInformation() {
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                    Log.d("Profile", response);
                    String json = response;
                    try {
                        // Facebook Profile JSON data
                        JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                        // getting name of the user
                        final String name = profile.getString("name");

                        // getting email of the user
                        final String email = profile.getString("email");

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        });


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                }

                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });

        }


         @Deprecated
         public void logoutFromFacebook() {

                mAsyncRunner.logout(MainActivity.this, new RequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                        Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // make Login button visible
                                    login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    // making all remaining buttons invisible
                                    getData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }

                            });

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                            Object state) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                            Object state) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                    }
                });
            }

 @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onDestroy();
         // if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //  }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that  `onDestroy()` method will call always called on activity finish.

So better you put that code of session clear in `onPause()` method.

UPDATE:

Do One more thing

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("access_token", null);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 =  getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor2.putLong("access_expires", 0);
editor2.commit();
```

Add this lines in your facebookLogout() method.

Because In your code I found that you are not checking for the session you checking this two variables to identify whether the user is login or not.

Comment: @ Biraj Zalavadia i want after logout button is click,on login button again he get the dialogbox asked for id and password as it ask after install the app,but it always show already login toast

Comment: yes i tried ..but showing toast only @  Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: if i uninstall and again install then only i get that dialog asking for credentials otherwise only toast is visible

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely to onDestroy to be called just after quiting your activity (finish()). it's usually the case but ondestroy can be called after a considerable delay.

you can call your cleaning code in onPause and you can enhance it like following:

```
@Override protected void onDestroy() {

      super.onDestroy();

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null){
       session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
     }
 }
```

Comment: @ Slim again it is showing the toast only,not showing the login dialogbox that ask for facebook credentials

Answer (score 0):

it is not known when onDestroy is going to call. it only invoke onStop and then move your activity to back. It is happen because if user again start this application , it will not have to load activity in ram again.because it a costly process to load activity in ram. so dont do any saving of data or any other work in onDestroy.move that work in onPause or in onStop.

[read more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)